# Oracle database trigger before insert, reject invalid insertions but keep valid ones

Tags: oracle, database-design, triggers, oracle11g

I'm new to oracle, here I'm trying to write a trigger before insertion.

Before insertion of one table, I get values from the query and search in other tables based on those. If I can't find related data in other tables, then the insertion should fail.

But I want to only reject invalid insertions and keep those are valid. I've tried raising an error, which would fail the whole transaction. So what should I do?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SOME_TRIGGER"
BEFORE
INSERT ON "SOME_TABLE"
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    var_name VAR_TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var_name FROM OTHER_TABLE 
    WHERE OTHER_TABLE.SOME_COLUMN = :NEW.SOME_COLUMN;
IF (var_name < 1)   
THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'ERR MESSAGE');
ELSE
      NULL;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Well, then you either have to commit each insert individually, which may not be what you want. That's the whole point of a transaction - all or nothing.  Why not do the check in the calling app instead and have it filter the data that fails validation?  Suggest you read [Ask Tom's Trouble with Triggers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html)

Comment: This sounds like you should have a look at constraints. Generally this type of checks can be achieved by constraints.

Comment: The value which you are searching is some kind of a common key i.e. `Primary Key`? As pointed out by @steve, these type of validations could be achieved using constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the LOG ERRORS clause of the INSERT statement.

e.g.

```
EXECUTE DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG('some_table', 'some_table_errors');
INSERT INTO some_table
SELECT some_column
FROM other_table
LOG ERRORS INTO some_table_errors('my_errors') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

It also looks like you are trying to implement a foreign key constraint programmatically. It would be much better to implement this via a declaration. You may want to look at the PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY clauses of the CREATE TABLE statement.